# How come when i read an in from System.in I get a completely different value than I read in?

Tags: java, input, system.in

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int i = System.in.read();

    System.out.println(i);

}
```

When I input 13 for example it prints out 49..? why is that?  And how do I fix that?

Comment: What does `System.in.read()` do?

Comment: It reads a line of input

Comment: Does it _really_? What makes you think that?

Comment: You might want to double check that in the api docs. Then look at `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: For your convenience: [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)

Answer (score 2):

read reads single character and `1` (character)'s  `int` value is 49